# Why is Grpc.Core NuGet package so big?

Tags: c#, nuget, grpc

The latest Grpc.Core NuGet package is a hefty 150 MB.  It seems to have grown steadily over its life.  Here are a few examples:

- v1.17.1 (Dec 2018) 48.34 MB
- v2.23.1 (Aug 2019) 68.11 MB
- v2.30.0 (Jun 2020) 150.28 MB

Maybe this is not apples-to-apples, but to pick a random example the Entity Framework Core package is 859 KB.

I'm curious what's in this package that makes it so darn big.  Is there perhaps some stuff that is not totally essential for someone who is creating a simple C# service?

Comment: Its big because there is a lot of stuff in there, "*Is there perhaps some stuff that is not totally essential for someone who is creating a simple C# service*" - of course.

Comment: Check out some of the examples of creating simple clients and services, you will notice they target more fine grained packages like Grpc.Net.Client ect

Comment: Yep, after posting my question I found that I could get what I wanted from the combination of Google.Protobuf and Grpc.Core.Api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core functionality of the package containing libraries and build scripts totals at less than 2 MB. What makes to package so large is that it contains runtime files for *Linux*, *Windows* and *Mac OSX*, as well as native libraries for *iOS* and *Android*. Let's look at the package contents for details, but only the first two or three directory levels.

- build [8 KB]

  - MonoAndroid10
  - net45
  - Xamarin.iOS10
- lib [1.9 MB]

  - net45
  - netstandard1.5
  - netstandard2.0
- runtimes **[137.5 MB]**

  - linux [113.4 MB]
  - win [12.4 MB]
  - osx [11.7 MB]
- native **[424.6 MB]**

  - android [164.3 MB]

    - x86 [56.3 MB]
    - arm64-v8a [54.3 MB]
    - armeabi-v7a [53.7 MB]
  - ios [260.3 MB]

You might wonder why the mobile runtimes are that much large than the ones for *Windows* or *MacOS*. It turns out that for *Android* there are native libraries for three different architectures each around 50 MB and for *iOS* there is not only an `*_csharp_ext` library, but a whole `libgrpc` library with 260 MB alone. For *Linux* there are two libraries for x86 and x64 with 44.8 MB and 68.6 MB. However, I cannot tell why the abovementioned libraries are so much larger in size than their counterparts for *Windows* or *MacOS*.

The package probably covers much more than you actually need in your project and you might want to use a more language-specific package that suits your scenario as suggested in the [Grpc repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc).

Comment: It’s still surprising why the Linux and “native” (mobile) runtimes are that much bigger than the ones for Windows and macOS.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have added a little more detail about these differences in size.